# Iterate through JSON-Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, parsing

I parsed a XML file and retrieved the following JSON-object.
The issue is that there are dashes in the json, which causes problems iterating through the object. I can not get rid off them unfortunately.

```js
$(function() {
  let json = JSON.parse('{"app-app":{"$":{},"notneeded":"123","mapped":{"$":{},"match-match":[{"$":{},"name":"Foo 1","url":"/Bar 1"},{"$":{},"name":"Foo 2","url":"/Bar 2"},{"$":{},"name":"Foo 3","url":"Bar 3"}]},"Nothing":"123"}}');

  var foo = Object.keys(json['app-app']['mapped']['match-match']).length;
  for (var i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
    console.log(json['app-app']['mapped']['match-match'][i].name);
    console.log(json['app-app']['mapped']['match-match'][i].url);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to iterate through the object and extract every "match" children. Something like this:

```
return [
            {
                name: 'Foo 1',
                url:  'Bar 1'
            },
            [...]
       ]
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: `value.app.mapped.match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), to iterate over your json array and return your custom structure, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  let json = JSON.parse('{"app-app":{"$":{},"notneeded":"123","mapped":{"$":{},"match-match":[{"$":{},"name":"Foo 1","url":"/Bar 1"},{"$":{},"name":"Foo 2","url":"/Bar 2"},{"$":{},"name":"Foo 3","url":"Bar 3"}]},"Nothing":"123"}}');


  var result = json['app-app']['mapped']['match-match'].map(function(item) {
    return {
      "name": item.name,
      "url": item.url
    };
  });
  console.dir(result);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let json = JSON.parse('{"app":{"$":{},"notneeded":"123","mapped":{"$":{},"match":[{"$":{},"name":"Foo 1","url":"/Bar 1"},{"$":{},"name":"Foo 2","url":"/Bar 2"},{"$":{},"regex":"Foo 3","configuration":"Bar 3"}]},"Nothing":"123"}}');
console.log(json['app']['mapped']['match']);
```

Comment: @AppRoyale Don't update your question with tries. This will lead to a misunderstanding of the first idea. + Check the array and you will see that the last object has `regex` and `configuration` as properties and not `name` and `url`